# Which Neo4j endpoint is in use in these two cases?

Tags: database, rest, neo4j, graph-databases, endpoint

I'm using Neo4J in server mode, and the cypher queries are being sent over via REST API. I'm also measuring the performance of queries, that is why I use two different libraries:

(Standard?) neo4j-rest-graphdb.jar where I'm establishing a connection with class RestAPIFacade:`RestAPI graphDb = new RestAPIFacade(...);`

and

Neo4J-jDBC-2.1.4.jar
Where I use `DriverManager.getConnection(..)` to get a connection.

As far as my understanding goes, everything here uses REST, there is no tcp/socket connection for Neo4j yet. For REST API you can use different **endpoints** (e.g. transactional HTTP endpoint, ...), which would explain different execution times. jDBC version is more than a half faster on a FOAF query. 
Why is that so and what is going on behind the user code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC uses the transactional endpoint which streams data, 
but which also returns less payload.

It is not the fastest implementation yet.

If you want that, you can perhaps do it yourself, like shown here:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html#_sending_cypher

I also have a faster implementation here, which I still need to merge into the JDBC driver:

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-remoting-cypher/blob/master/src/main/java/transaction/CypherTransaction.java